# Mutexes with the same name

Tags: c#, mutex

I'm relatively new to C# programming and some days ago, I came across the term `mutex`. It was used in the sense of avoiding running multiple instances of the same application. I was actually reading a book on WPF (using C#, of course) so there was no deep explanation on C# (the author wrote it for people with sufficient knowledge of C#).
It was used in this form:

```
Mutex mutex;
// ...

// Check for existing instance
string mutexName = "MyCompanyName.MyAppName";
bool createdNew;
mutex = new Mutex(true, mutexName, out createdNew);

// If there is an existing instance, shut down this one
if(!createdNew) { Shutdown(); }
```

My explanation of a mutex is that it is sort of a system-wide type. All single-instance applications access all mutexes in a system to prevent multiple instances. Also. a mutex should have a unique `name`. (Of course, I stand to be corrected; that's my own explanation so it could be wrong).

Suppose there happens to be a mutex named `"mutexConflict"` created by an application A while another application B (which was created by a completely different author) has its own mutex also named `"mutexConflict"`. If A is already running and B is about to be run, isn't there supposed to be a conflict? Will B run?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there **is** supposed to be a conflict. That's why you choose such names for your mutexes that are likely to be unique.

If you want only one instance of your application to run at a time, all you need is open a named mutex in the beginning of your program, and, if it exists, shut down. That's the point of your example and that's how it's implemented usually.

Comment: I implied that application B could have been written by another author whom, very likely, I don't know. It would be silly of me if I wrote both apps and I named the mutices(?) similarly.

Comment: @afaolek: It would make sense if you want to mandate that they do not simultaneously run at the same time.

Comment: @afaolek: And still, you can make up a name that no one is likely to think of even if you don't know them. For example:"Hold the newsreader's nose squarely, waiter, or friendly milk will countermand my trousers."

Answer (score 1):

If it for this reason that the example used "MyCompanyName.MyAppName", as it is unlikely that another team in your company is developing an application with the same name as you

Comment: That was the example in the book. It could happen although the probability of such an occurrence is very minute.

Answer (score 1):

This is EXACTLY the point of a mutex. You have some key, and you want to provide mutually exclusive use of that key.